# (admit.java) My little program is not passing an integer between methods

Tags: java

I am a bit confused, I have a little program I wrote for a school assignment, the constraints I am required to work with is that no method can contain more than 15 lines of code, and we cannot use any for next loops.

What I cant seem to figure out is why I am able to pass an integer to my rounding method and it even returns the rounded value, but then it jumps back to my if / then statements (which it shouldnt be doing) and does not pass the variable.

It is a very rudimentary program I know...my coding skills are not very good, but any help would be appreciated.

The variables I need passed back are testscore and GPA, those need to go back to the main method so they can be stored to new variables and finally pushed off into the results method.

Im still pretty new to coding and the community and how things work...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Admit {
   public static void main(String[] Args) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      Introduction();
      double testscore = 0;
      double GPA = 0;
      int Student = 1;
      ACTSATScores(1,0,console);
      double StudentOneTestScore = testscore;
      GPAInfo(0,console);
      double StudentOneGPAScore = GPA;
      Student = 2;
      ACTSATScores(2,0,console);
      double StudentTwoTestScore = testscore;
      GPAInfo(0,console);
      double StudentTwoGPAScore = GPA;
      DisplayResults(StudentOneTestScore,StudentOneGPAScore,StudentTwoTestScore,StudentTwoGPAScore);
      }

   public static void Introduction() {
      System.out.println("This program compares two applicants to");
      System.out.println("determine which one seems like the stronger");
      System.out.println("applicant.  For each candidate I will need");
      System.out.println("either SAT or ACT scores plus a weighted GPA.");
      System.out.println();   
   }

   public static double ACTSATScores(int Student,double testscore,Scanner console) {
      System.out.println("Information for applicant #" + Student + ":");
      System.out.print("do you have 1) SAT scores or 2) ACT scores? ");
      int ACTSAT = console.nextInt();
         if ( ACTSAT == 1) {
            SAT(Student,testscore,console);
         }
         if ( ACTSAT == 2) {
            ACT(Student,testscore,console);
         }
         return testscore;
   }

   public static double SAT(int Student,double testscore,Scanner console) {
       System.out.print("SAT math? ");
       int SATMath = console.nextInt();
       System.out.print("SAT critical reading? ");
       int SATReading = console.nextInt();
       System.out.print("SAT writing? ");
       int SATWriting = console.nextInt();
       testscore = ( ( 2 * SATMath + SATReading + SATWriting ) / 32);
       System.out.println("exam score = " +  roundNumber(testscore));
       return ( ( 2 * SATMath + SATReading + SATWriting ) / 32);
   }

   public static double ACT(int Student,double testscore,Scanner console) {
       System.out.print("ACT English? ");
       int ACTEnglish = console.nextInt();
       System.out.print("ACT math? ");
       int ACTMath = console.nextInt();
       System.out.print("ACT reading? ");
       int ACTReading = console.nextInt();
       System.out.print("ACT science? ");
       int ACTScience = console.nextInt();
       testscore = ( ( 2 * ACTMath + ACTEnglish + ACTReading + ACTScience ) / 1.8 );
       System.out.println("exam score = " + roundNumber(testscore));
       return testscore;
   }

   public static double GPAInfo(double GPA,Scanner console) {
       System.out.print("overall GPA? ");
       double OverallGPA = console.nextDouble();
       System.out.print("max GPA? ");
       double MaxGPA = console.nextDouble();
       System.out.print("Transcript Multiplier? ");
       double TranscriptMultiplier = console.nextDouble();
       GPA = ( OverallGPA / MaxGPA * 100 * TranscriptMultiplier );
       System.out.println("GPA score = " + roundNumber(GPA));
       return GPA;
    }

    public static double roundNumber(double number) {
      return (Math.round(number * 10)) / 10.0;
   }

    public static double DisplayResults(double StudentOneTestScore, double StudentOneGPAScore, double StudentTwoTestScore, double StudentTwoGPAScore) {
       System.out.println("First applicant overall score = " + StudentOneTestScore + StudentOneGPAScore);
       System.out.println("Second applicant overall score = " + StudentTwoTestScore + StudentTwoGPAScore);
       if ( StudentOneTestScore + StudentOneGPAScore > StudentTwoTestScore + StudentTwoGPAScore ) {
       System.out.println("The first applicant seems to be better");
       }
       else if ( StudentOneTestScore + StudentOneGPAScore < StudentTwoTestScore + StudentTwoGPAScore ) {
          System.out.println("The second applicant seems to be better");
       }
       else {
          System.out.println("The two applicants seem to be equal");
       }
       return StudentOneTestScore;
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
This program compares two applicants to
determine which one seems like the stronger
applicant.  For each candidate I will need
either SAT or ACT scores plus a weighted GPA.
 
Information for applicant #1:
    do you have 1) SAT scores or 2) ACT scores? 1
    SAT math? 450
    SAT critical reading? 530
    SAT writing? 490
    exam score = 60.0
    overall GPA? 3.4
    max GPA? 4.0
    Transcript Multiplier? 0.9
    GPA score = 76.5
 
Information for applicant #2:
    do you have 1) SAT scores or 2) ACT scores? 2
    ACT English? 25
    ACT math? 20
    ACT reading? 18
    ACT science? 15
    exam score = 54.4
    overall GPA? 3.3
    max GPA? 4.0
    Transcript Multiplier? 0.95
    GPA score = 78.4
 
First applicant overall score  = 136.5
Second applicant overall score = 132.8
The first applicant seems to be better
```

My output

```
This program compares two applicants to
determine which one seems like the stronger
applicant.  For each candidate I will need
either SAT or ACT scores plus a weighted GPA.

Information for applicant #1:
do you have 1) SAT scores or 2) ACT scores? 1
SAT math? 450
SAT critical reading? 530
SAT writing? 490
exam score = 60.0
overall GPA? 3.4
max GPA? 4.0
Transcript Multiplier? 0.9
GPA score = 76.5
Information for applicant #2:
do you have 1) SAT scores or 2) ACT scores? 2
ACT English? 25
ACT math? 20
ACT reading? 18
ACT science? 15
exam score = 54.4
overall GPA? 3.3
max GPA? 4.0
Transcript Multiplier? 0.95
GPA score = 78.4
First applicant overall score = 0.00.0
Second applicant overall score = 0.00.0
The two applicants seem to be equal
```

Corrected Code for anyone that needs it

```
import java.util.*;

public class Admit {
   public static void main(String[] Args) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      Introduction();
      int Student = 1;
      double StudentOneTestScore = ACTSATScores(1,console);
      double StudentOneGPAScore = GPAInfo(0,console);
      Student = 2;
      double StudentTwoTestScore = ACTSATScores(1,console);
      double StudentTwoGPAScore = GPAInfo(0,console);
      DisplayResults(StudentOneTestScore,StudentOneGPAScore,StudentTwoTestScore,StudentTwoGPAScore);
      }

   public static void Introduction() {
      System.out.println("This program compares two applicants to");
      System.out.println("determine which one seems like the stronger");
      System.out.println("applicant.  For each candidate I will need");
      System.out.println("either SAT or ACT scores plus a weighted GPA.");
      System.out.println();   
   }

   public static double ACTSATScores(int Student,Scanner console) {
      double testscore = 0;
      System.out.println("Information for applicant #" + Student + ":");
      System.out.print("    do you have 1) SAT scores or 2) ACT scores? ");
      int ACTSAT = console.nextInt();
         if ( ACTSAT == 1) {
            testscore = SAT(console);
         }
         if ( ACTSAT == 2) {
            testscore = ACT(console);
         }
         return testscore;
   }

   public static double SAT(Scanner console) {
       System.out.print("    SAT math? ");
       int SATMath = console.nextInt();
       System.out.print("    SAT critical reading? ");
       int SATReading = console.nextInt();
       System.out.print("    SAT writing? ");
       int SATWriting = console.nextInt();       
       double testscore = ( ( 2 * SATMath + SATReading + SATWriting ) / 32);
       System.out.println("    exam score = " +  roundNumber(testscore));
       return testscore;
   }

   public static double ACT(Scanner console) {
       System.out.print("    ACT English? ");
       int ACTEnglish = console.nextInt();
       System.out.print("    ACT math? ");
       int ACTMath = console.nextInt();
       System.out.print("    ACT reading? ");
       int ACTReading = console.nextInt();
       System.out.print("    ACT science? ");
       int ACTScience = console.nextInt();
       double testscore = ( ( 2 * ACTMath + ACTEnglish + ACTReading + ACTScience ) / 1.8 );
       System.out.println("    exam score = " + roundNumber(testscore));
       return testscore;
   }

   public static double GPAInfo(double GPA,Scanner console) {
       System.out.print("    overall GPA? ");
       double OverallGPA = console.nextDouble();
       System.out.print("    max GPA? ");
       double MaxGPA = console.nextDouble();
       System.out.print("    Transcript Multiplier? ");
       double TranscriptMultiplier = console.nextDouble();
       GPA = ( OverallGPA / MaxGPA * 100 * TranscriptMultiplier );
       System.out.println("    GPA score = " + roundNumber(GPA));
       System.out.println();
       return GPA;
    }

    public static double roundNumber(double number) {
      return (Math.round(number * 10)) / 10.0;
   }

   public static double finalScore(double TestScore, double GPAScore) {
       return TestScore + GPAScore;
   }

    public static double DisplayResults(double StudentOneTestScore, double StudentOneGPAScore, double StudentTwoTestScore, double StudentTwoGPAScore) {
       double StudentOneScore = finalScore(StudentOneTestScore,StudentOneGPAScore);
       double StudentTwoScore = finalScore(StudentTwoTestScore,StudentTwoGPAScore);
       System.out.println("First applicant overall score = " + roundNumber(StudentOneScore)); //StudentOneTestScore + StudentOneGPAScore);
       System.out.println("Second applicant overall score = " + roundNumber(StudentTwoScore)); //StudentTwoTestScore + StudentTwoGPAScore);
       if ( StudentOneTestScore + StudentOneGPAScore > StudentTwoTestScore + StudentTwoGPAScore ) {
       System.out.println("The first applicant seems to be better");
       } else if ( StudentOneTestScore + StudentOneGPAScore < StudentTwoTestScore + StudentTwoGPAScore ) {
          System.out.println("The second applicant seems to be better");
       } else {
          System.out.println("The two applicants seem to be equal");
       }
       return StudentOneTestScore;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a problem when using methods, returning types and inmutable types.
In the main section:

```
  double testscore = 0;
  double GPA = 0;
  int Student = 1;
  ACTSATScores(1,0,console);
  double StudentOneTestScore = testscore;
  GPAInfo(0,console);
  double StudentOneGPAScore = GPA;
  Student = 2;
  ACTSATScores(2,0,console);
  double StudentTwoTestScore = testscore;
```

You are assigning those variables the value "testscore". But you really never change that value, and the way you wrote the methods makes me believe that you are expecting testscore to change inside the methods.

Try printing the value of testscore in the main to see that it does not change its value (it should be always 0 in that main). This might be what you are looking for:

```
double StudentOneTestScore = ACTSATScores(1,0,console);
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is neat...I can literally assign a returned value to a variable? I need to try this!